# Diferença entre NULO, vazio e em branco Python

Tags: python, null, pyodbc

Estou fazendo um Data Quality que recebe uma lista com dados de um Banco de Dados e tenho duas regras:

1. Campos nulos: Campos que venham preenchidos com a palavra NULL
2. Campos brancos/vazios: Campos que venham em branco ou vazios

Para a regra do `NULL` estou usando:

```
if (pd.isnull(lista[linha2][linha])):
    print("Alguma coisa")
```

e reconhece o campo como *NaN*.

Como eu faço para campos em branco ou vazio?

E o tipo do campo influencia (ex: str e float)?

Comment: "Data Quality" na minha época era uma forma bonita de falar de um chuncho.

Comment: Aliás, o que você está usando para trazer registros do banco de dados?

Comment: Não sei a sintaxe da linguagem Python, mas no PHP seria algo como: `if (lista[linha2][linha] == '')`

Comment: Estou usando a biblioteca pyodbc. Tinha tentado dessa forma e não tinha funcionado, agora funcionou..vai saber né! Obrigada!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No Python, se você fizer apenas

```
if variavel:
    ...
```

Qualquer valor que seja analizado como verdadeiro passará no teste. Não ficou muito claro, pelo menos para mim, o que seria este objeto `pd` que você executa o método `isnull`, se for do Pandas de fato será verificado se o valor é `None` ou `NaN`. Sem o Pandas, poderia ser feito:

```
if lista[linha2][linha] is None:
    ...
```

Para valores `NaN`:

```
import math

if math.isnan(lista[linha2][linha]):
    ...
```

Para campos em branco possivelmente você receberá uma string vazia, então:

```
if lista[linha2][linha] == "":
    ...
```

Comment: pd é da biblioteca Pandas mesmo! Obrigada pela resposta!