# Django – Diferença de Null e Blank

Tags: python, django

Estou com uma certa dificuldade de entender a real diferença de `null` e `blank` no django,

Por exemplo:

Nesse código, ao meu entender o campo nome será `NOTNULL` no banco de dados, mas e esse blank? Ele não é redundante com o null???

```
class Empregado(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=False, null=False)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se vc define `null=True` (o contrário de NOT NULL) em um campo de seu modelo (uma coluna do BD), ao entrar com valores em branco para tipos como `DateTimeField` e `ForeignKey` serão armazenados como NULL em seu BD, isso é muito útil para as FKs, quando vc quer que o item relacionado possa ser deixado em branco.

Definindo `blank=True` você não obriga que o campo seja preenchido nos formulários, podendo ficar em branco, se definir `blank=False` esse campo será obrigatório, isto é, não poderá ficar em branco.

A combinação dos dois, a primeira vista, pode parecer não fazer sentido, mas se você analisar sob a ótica da harmonia do front-end com o back-end, verá que se você permitir que um campo fique em branco (ou seja omitido) em um formulário, também precisará que o banco de dados permita valores NULL para esse campo, com exceção de `CharFields` e `TextFields` que são armazenados como uma string vazia ('') ao invés de NULL, no django.

**Na [documentação](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/) tem a seguinte nota ao explicar `blank`:**
Note que `blank` é diferente de null. `null` é especificamente relacionado ao banco de dados, enquanto o `blank` é relacionado à validação. Se um campo tiver `blank=True`, a validação de um formulário permitirá a entrada de um valor vazio. Se o campo tiver `blank=False`, então o campo será obrigatório.

Comment: Obrigado, me ajudou muito!!

Answer (score 6):

Quanto ao `null` está correto. Ao utilizar `null=False` a coluna ficará no banco como `NOT NULL`; o contrário também é válido.

Quanto ao `blank`, ele definirá o comportamento da aplicação quando o valor for vazio (e vazio é diferente de nulo).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- [O que realmente significa NULL?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90363/5878)
- [Diferença entre NULO, vazio e em branco Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/204767/5878)

Ao utilizar `blank=False` você está dizendo que o valor deste campo não pode ser vazio, ou seja, ele será obrigatório ao preencher o formulário. Ele terá muito mais impacto no próprio Python, durante as validações, do que no banco de dados propriamente dito.